# Detect if scroll to element (using getBoundingClientRect(); )

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport, getboundingclientrect

I try to detect is element is in viewport via using  [getBoundingClientRect();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)

But my case I want to add some function when (only one) element is on the viewport like click on some html anchor tag

**When :**

- Element's top >= 0
- window.scrollTop =< Element's height

**Example :**

Block#A (TOP=0, HEIGHT=200)

Block#B (TOP=200, HEIGHT=450)

Block#C (TOP=450, HEIGHt=600)

When top viewport is **100** so I will do something with Block#A

**So far my code :**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var elements = $('.block');
  var len = elements.length;

  for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var statement = 'i have no idea';
    if(statement) {
         element.doSomething();
         break;
    }
  }

});
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/5LK3U/

Comment: What does element.getBoundingClientRect().top returns ? You could do it with $(document).scrollTop, but this method can be interesting.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Yes native and faster @enguerranws

Comment: scrollTop() or getBoundingClientRect() ?

Comment: $(windoow) should be $(window) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Done with this :**

```
function ViewportDetect(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.bottom > 0 && rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}
```